# strict operator not working for value 0 (val === null) in angular js

Tags: angularjs, if-statement, null

Im using a condition in angular js as follows:

```
if( selectedVal == '' && selectedVal === null)
{
  /*some function()*/
}
```

When the selectedVal is 0(zero), the condition is getting true. Please some one help me to resolve..

Comment: Can you provide a plunker, or the full code? Are you sure you are using === instead of ==  ?

Comment: give us fiddle or running example?

Comment: ya its my mistake. Once i include === for ' ' check its working...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: == equal value whatever the type of variable may be, but === equals also checka for the type of variables are equal or not.